# How do you convert object 'this' to a string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a string to an array, while the string is the object `this`. The function doing this is below:

```
    function reverseString() { 
        // uses Prototype Javascript Framework function 'toArray()'
        return this.toArray().reverse().join('');
    }
```

Is it possible to convert object `this` to a string, or is there a different/better way of doing this?

Comment: :P simpler than I thought it would be. My bad. Had to ask though, Bing failed me.

Answer (score 7):

```
this.toString()
```

Comment: Exactly.  This is a standard practice when it comes to taking an object's output in a formatted String.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to convert to JSON - include [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) and use `JSON.stringify(this)`